# Jquery grid expand/collapse div siblings gallery

Tags: jquery, grid, gallery

Working on a gallery where there is a grid of 4 images and when you click on one the image, this same image expands and another division with some content shows up right next to it, moving the rest of images down.

My main question is:
I'm not sure how to make column number 4 not move when the new division shows up.
I've been playing around with css positions with no success

It feels pretty solid but maybe I'm approaching it wrong, would this be easier with Isotope?

**This fiddle is what I came up with:**

http://jsfiddle.net/jupago/xq279/32/

```
$(".photo").click(function(e) {
    if( $(this).prev().hasClass("open") ) {
        $(this).prev().removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
            }
    else {
        // if other menus are open remove open class and add closed
        $(this).siblings().prev().removeClass("open").addClass("closed"); 
        $(this).prev().removeClass("closed").addClass("open");
    }
     if( $(this).hasClass("opaque") ) {
        $(this).removeClass("opaque");
        }
    else {
        // change opacity of selected image
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("opaque"); 
        $(this).addClass("opaque");
    }
});
```

Comment: So what's happening is your text box 4 is being put in before your picture 4. Just put the text box after the picture instead of before and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyS that's what I'm trying to figure out, since I wanted to simplify is as much as possible I'm having all call the previous div, do you know how would I have only the 4th column call the next div?

Comment: Let me take a look, on the other hand if you gave the 4th text 80px width !important then it'd also fit. I'll look at getting the 4th box to be called after vs before.

Comment: Thanks I'm a bit annoyed by the constant shuffling of images (even thought thats what they requested) So i created another where the width of expanding div is 100%, it seems to work better

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jupago/S4q8L/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fiddled around a bit and came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/S3QpB/

HTML: I moved the box divs for row 4 after and gave them ids so I could test against them in the javascript.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="gallerybox column1">TEXT for image 1</div>
<div class="photo"><img src="http://goo.gl/VEEw3z"/></div>

<div class="gallerybox column2">TEXT for image 2</div>
<div class="photo"><img src="http://goo.gl/VEEw3z"/></div>

<div class="gallerybox column3">TEXT for image 3</div>
<div class="photo"><img src="http://goo.gl/VEEw3z"/></div>


<div class="photo" id="box-4"><img src="http://goo.gl/VEEw3z"/></div>
<div class="gallerybox column4">TEXT for image 4</div>    

<div class="gallerybox column1">TEXT for image 1</div>
<div class="photo"><img src="http://goo.gl/VEEw3z"/></div>

<div class="gallerybox column2">TEXT for image 2</div>
<div class="photo"><img src="http://goo.gl/VEEw3z"/></div>

<div class="gallerybox column3">TEXT for image 3</div>
<div class="photo"><img src="http://goo.gl/VEEw3z"/></div>

<div class="photo" id="box-4-2"><img src="http://goo.gl/VEEw3z"/></div>
<div class="gallerybox column4">TEXT for image 4</div>        

<div class="gallerybox column1">TEXT for image 1</div>
<div class="photo"><img src="http://goo.gl/VEEw3z"/></div>

<div class="gallerybox column2">TEXT for image 2</div>
<div class="photo"><img src="http://goo.gl/VEEw3z"/></div>

<div class="gallerybox column3">TEXT for image 3</div>
<div class="photo"><img src="http://goo.gl/VEEw3z"/></div>

<div class="photo" id="box-4-3"><img src="http://goo.gl/VEEw3z"/></div>
<div class="gallerybox column4">TEXT for image 4</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".photo").click(function(e) {
if ( ($(this).attr('id') !== "box-4") && ($(this).attr('id') !== "box-4-2") && ($(this).attr('id') !== "box-4-3") ) {
    if( $(this).prev().hasClass("open") ) {

        $(this).prev().removeClass("open").addClass("closed");

        }

    else {

        // if other menus are open remove open class and add closed

        $(this).siblings().prev().removeClass("open").addClass("closed"); 

        $(this).prev().removeClass("closed").addClass("open");

    }

     if( $(this).hasClass("opaque") ) {

        $(this).removeClass("opaque");

        }

    else {

        // if other menus are open remove open class and add closed

        $(this).siblings().removeClass("opaque"); 

        $(this).addClass("opaque");

  }
} else {
    if( $(this).next().hasClass("open") ) {
        $(this).next().removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
        }
    else {
    $(this).siblings().next().removeClass("open").addClass("closed"); 
        $(this).next().removeClass("closed").addClass("open");
    }
    if( $(this).hasClass("opaque") ) {
        $(this).removeClass("opaque");
        }
    else {
        // if other menus are open remove open class and add closed
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("opaque"); 
        $(this).addClass("opaque");
  }
}
});
```

Comment: thanks!!!!! I'll show this version along with this: jsfiddle.net/jupago/S4q8L and see which one sounds like a better choice, the images are twice as big so the constant shuffling might get annoying. thanks again!!!!